# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8, elementtree

I guess this error is coming from the fact that the XML file is in UTF-8, but Python wants to handle it as an ASCII? I have parsed the xml correctly but when I try to print the contents of the XML I get this error because there are some foreign Unicode characters. Can someone try fix this code below? May be encode unicode string to ASCII? Thanks!!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = ET.parse('/Downloads/sample.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    a=[]

    for child in root.iter():
        if child.tag == "author":
            a.append(child.text)
        if child.tag == "title":
            for name in a:
                print "%s\t%s" % (name, child.text)
            a=[]
```

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback.

Comment: You have a unicode object (thats the `u'` part), to print it - you need to tell Python what encoding to use.  It is trying ASCII (its default), but it can't find those bytes.

Comment: What is your console? If it is the Windows command prompt, give up, you cannot easily/reliably print Unicode to Windows from standard library applications.